# Problem : Certificate for multi Clients of WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, certificate

- If My WCF service have big number of clients through the
  Internet,then whether should all of them share the same Client
  Certificate(X509)?
- And if their certificates should be unique , what should I do on the
  WCF to identify all the certificates?
- Last question: Must I import the server-side certificate  into
  TrustedPeople location on every Client ? (Which seems to be
  troublesome and any way convenient?  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming a WCF service hosted on IIS using HTTPS with client certificate.

- This depends on your requirements. If you want to use the client cert to identify any valid client for your service then no. If you want to authorise each client individually then yes. Is your client for B2B scenario then you may have to use individual certificate for each client.
- If hosting on IIS as long as the client cert is installed in Trusted People it should just work. For self hosting a custom certificate validator class can be implemented to do thus
- This is not required if the cet is issued by a trusted certification authority e.g. Verisign. Otherwise I think you can use a Base64 encoded value of the cert in endpoint identity element as shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thnaks,save me a day.